# How to connect to MQTT broker from NodeMCU with SSL?

Tags: mqtt

I cannot connect to a MQTT broker from a NodeMCU, when using SSL.

This is the error message:

> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-4 try again in 5 seconds.

When connecting to the same broker via other software like MQTTX or IOT MQTT panel, it does work fine, just the NodeMCU doesn't connect. What does work is using a local IP and port 1883, but as soon as I use the public mqtt broker IP and port 8883, the NodeMCU cannot connect.

I am probably overlooking something. Is it necessary to include the server certificates in the arduino code?

This is the mosquitto.conf:

```
persistence true 
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
 
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd 

listener 1883
listener 8883
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.pem
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
```

And here is the sample Arduino Code.

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include "PubSubClient.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

const char* ssid = "MyWiFi";
const char* password = "MyBassword";

const char* mqtt_server = "MyMqttServer";
const char* mqtt_username = "MyUser"; 
const char* mqtt_password = "MyBassword"; 
int mqtt_port = 8883;

const char* mqtt_id = __DATE__ " " __TIME__;  //compile date that is used for a mostly unique identifier

 
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() 
{ 
    Serial.begin(115200);
    setup_wifi();
    setup_mqtt();
}
 
void setup_wifi() 
{
    delay(10);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
        {
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
        }

    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup_mqtt()
    {
        client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);
        client.setCallback(callback);

        Serial.println("Modbus RTU Master Online");
    }

  
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) 
    {  
        Serial.print("Message arrived [");
        Serial.print(topic);
    }

void reconnect() 
    {
        // Loop until we're reconnected to MQTT
        while (!client.connected()) 
            {
                Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
                // Attempt to connect
                if (client.connect(mqtt_id, mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) 
                    {
                        Serial.println("connected");
                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        Serial.print("failed, rc=");
                        Serial.print(client.state());
                        Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
                        // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
                        delay(5000);
                    }
            }
    }


void loop() 
{
    delay(1000);
    
    if (!client.connected()) 
        {
            reconnect();
        }

    client.loop();
}
```

Comment: use `WiFiClientSecure espClient;`

Comment: That changes the error from rc=-4 to rc=-2. When removing the certfile and keyfile from mosquitto.conf, the NodeMCU can connect via port 8883, but that defeats the purpose of using the cert.